# How to run strored procedure CREATE query using jpa

Tags: java, jpa, stored-procedures, jpa-2.1

I want create stored procedure using existing query. I am not able run the whole query, it's throwing SQLGrammer exception.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT_SECURITY_PARAMETERS()
BEGIN
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER ' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:974)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.execute(ClientPreparedStatement.java:391)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.execute(CallableStatement.java:842)
```

My test code like below:

```
  @Test
    public void  procedureTest(){
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        StoredProcedureQuery  storedProcedureQuery = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("DELIMITER //\n" +
                "CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT_SECURITY_PARAMETERS()\n" +
                "BEGIN\n" +
                "DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000' SELECT 'SQLSTATE 23000' ErrorCode;\n" +
                "INSERT INTO TB_ASMI_SECURITY_PARAMETERS (APP_ID,MIN_NUM_NUM,MIN_NUM_SPCL_CHAR,MIN_NUM_UPPER_CASE_CHAR,MIN_LENGTH,MAX_LENGTH,PASS_CHANGE_FREQ,LAST_N_PASS_NOT_TO_USE,SESSION_TIMEOUT,NOOFFAILEDCOUNTS,CREATE_USER_ID,CREATE_TS,VERSION_NO,SERVER_TOKEN,FAIL_COUNT_TIMEOUT,PASSWORD_COUNT,DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION,ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_ENTRY,AUTO_APPROVE,PWD_COMM_CHANNEL,AUTH_STATUS,MULTIPLE_SESSION_ALLOWED,OTP_LENGTH,OTP_VALIDATION_COUNT,OTP_EXPIRY,OTP_RESEND,OTP_FORMAT,OTP_RESEND_COUNT,OTP_RESEND_LOCK_TIMEOUT,OTP_REGEN_COUNT,DATA_INTEGRITY,TXN_LOG_REQ,TXN_LOG_PAYLOAD,FMW_TXN_REQ,FMW_TXN_PAYLOAD, ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRY)\n" +
                " VALUES('Admin',1,1,1,8,32,30,1,'3000',5,'System',null,1,'ADMIN',5,5,'Y','N','Y','BOTH','A','Y','6','5','600','N','numeric','3','300','0','Y','Y','NONE','Y','NONE','1800');\n" +
                "END\n" +
                "//\n" +
                "DELIMITER ;");


        storedProcedureQuery.execute();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }
```

If I run from mysql worckbench it's working fine.

I tried different ways to run the script. Please help me in this. Thank you.

Comment: *MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//* ...  remove the "//" maybe?

Comment: Try removing "//\n" and other line breaks from the query .

Comment: I have tried removing "//\n" and line breaks also but no luck